# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton is not set at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.IsolatedStaticSingletonProvider$IsolatedStaticSingleton

Tags: jsf, tomcat, weld

I was created a JSF application using JBOSS tool and it worked fine.Then I added some libraries to my **WEB-INF > lib** folder and now it says an error as follows.What is the reason for it?

```
 INFO: Server startup in 7613 ms
Feb 15, 2015 9:45:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/ApplicationForm_1] threw exception [Singleton is not set] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Singleton is not set
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.api.helpers.IsolatedStaticSingletonProvider$IsolatedStaticSingleton.get(IsolatedStaticSingletonProvider.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.Container.instance(Container.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.instance(WeldPhaseListener.java:161)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:98)
    at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you using this listener `org.jboss.weld.servlet.WeldInitialListener`? See [here](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/236446).

Comment: Try to set init param in the web.xml of your web application:                     <init-param>
        <param-name>WELD_CONTEXT_ID_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>here set a unique id for each app, for example a  name of the web app war file                                                                     </param-value>
</init-param>